# Is it possible to create guest users using Java SDK graph api?

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using this code to create users in Azure Active Directory from Java SDK. I have installed all required packages and libraries.

```java
User user = new User();
user.accountEnabled = true;
user.displayName = "Kevin";
user.mailNickname = "kevin";
user.userPrincipalName = "kevin234@domain.onmicrosoft.com";
PasswordProfile passwordProfile = new PasswordProfile();
passwordProfile.forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true;
passwordProfile.password = "***********";
user.passwordProfile = passwordProfile;

graphClient.users()
    .buildRequest()
    .post(user);
```

I can create normal users but how to create guest users. I included `user.userType='guest'` in the above code

```java
user.userPrincipalName = "kevin234@hotmail.com";
user.userType='guest'; // I added this that outputs Invalid Request error

graphClient.users()
   .buildRequest()
   .post(user);
```

Is there any easy way to do that using Graph  API query? Can somebody suggest the changes I have to do in my code to achieve my scenario?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

To create guest users, you can make use of below query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
Content-type: application/json

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "kevin234@hotmail.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://yourwebsite.com"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the Portal, **guest user** created successfully like below:

[image]

You can find the **`code snippet`** in **Java** beside your query response like below:

[image]

**Code Sample in Java:**

```java
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

Invitation invitation = new Invitation();
invitation.invitedUserEmailAddress = "kevin234@hotmail.com";
invitation.inviteRedirectUrl = "https://yourwebsite.com";

graphClient.invitations()
.buildRequest()
.post(invitation);
```

**Credits:** [Create invitation - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#request)